# Setting column name in "group by" operation with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am a new user of the [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) package in R.
I am trying to give a name to the new column created by a "group by" command

```
> DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b"),c(2,3)),y=1:5) 
> DT
x y
1: a 1
2: a 2
3: b 3
4: b 4
5: b 5
> DT[,{z=sum(y);z+3},by=x]
x V1
1: a 6
2: b 15
```

1. I would like to name the V1 (default) column directly (not having to use colnames), is it possible?
2. Additionally, is it possible to perform several group by operations in one command, that would result in something like:

   ```
      x V1 V2
   1: a 6  something
   2: b 15 something
   ```

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
DT[,list(z=sum(y)+3,a=mean(y*z)),by=x]
   x  z  a
1: a  6  9
2: b 15 60
```

Since you are new to `data.table`, I recommend that you also study the help page of the `setnames` function as well as `?data.table` and the `data.table` vignettes.

Comment: +1 I wasn't sure if statquant wanted to rename the `by` column. I couldn't find either in ?data.table, the FAQs or S.O. easily (amazingly, so will add to ?data.table). If they do want that, it's:  `DT[,<same as you>,by=list(newname=x)]`.

Comment: @MatthewDowle Interesting. However, simply using `setnames` keeps the code simple. I usually prefer that over one-liners, which tend to get a bit complicated.

Comment: Interesting. Ok, I see what you mean.

Comment: Thaks guys, that's good for both questions. BTW Matthew, this package is a massive helper, I am handeling data.frame of 5e6 millions rows, and the ancient box I had was coring...not anymore with data.table.

Answer (score 2):

For conciseness, you can now use `.()` instead of `list()`

```
DT[, .(z=sum(y)+3, a=mean(y*z)), by=x]
```