# How can one work fully generically in data.table in R with column names in variables

Tags: r, data.table, calculated-columns, programmatically-created

What I'm looking for is a "best-practices-approved" alternative
to the following workaround / workflow. Consider
that I have a bunch of columns of similar data, and would like to perform a sequence of similar operations on these columns or sets of them, where the operations are of arbitrarily high complexity, and the groups of column names passed to each operation specified in a variable.

I realize this issue *sounds* contrived, but I run into it with surprising frequency. The examples are usually so messy that it is difficult to separate out the features relevant to this question, but I recently stumbled across one that was fairly straightforward to simplify for use as a MWE here:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)
 
the.table <- data.table(year=1991:1996,var1=floor(runif(6,400,1400)))
the.table[,`:=`(var2=var1/floor(runif(6,2,5)),
                var3=var1/floor(runif(6,2,5)))]
 
# Replicate data across months
new.table <- the.table[, list(asofdate=seq(from=ymd((year)*10^4+101),
                                           length.out=12,
                                           by="1 month")),by=year]
 
# Do a complicated procedure to each variable in some group.
var.names <- c("var1","var2","var3")
 
for(varname in var.names) {
    #As suggested in an answer to Link 3 above
    #Convert the column name to a 'quote' object
    quote.convert <- function(x) eval(parse(text=paste0('quote(',x,')')))
 
    #Do this for every column name I'll need
    varname <- quote.convert(varname)
    anntot <- quote.convert(paste0(varname,".annual.total"))
    monthly <- quote.convert(paste0(varname,".monthly"))
    rolling <- quote.convert(paste0(varname,".rolling"))
    scaled <- quote.convert(paste0(varname,".scaled"))
 
    #Perform the relevant tasks, using eval()
    #around every variable columnname I may want
    new.table[,eval(anntot):=
               the.table[,rep(eval(varname),each=12)]]
    new.table[,eval(monthly):=
               the.table[,rep(eval(varname)/12,each=12)]]
    new.table[,eval(rolling):=
               rollapply(eval(monthly),mean,width=12,
                         fill=c(head(eval(monthly),1),
                                tail(eval(monthly),1)))]
    new.table[,eval(scaled):=
               eval(anntot)/sum(eval(rolling))*eval(rolling),
              by=year]
}
```

Of course, the particular effect on the data and variables here is irrelevant, so please do not focus on it or suggest improvements to accomplishing what it accomplishes in this particular case. What I am looking for, rather, is a generic strategy for the workflow of repeatedly applying an arbitrarily complicated procedure of `data.table` actions to a list of columns or list of lists-of-columns, specified in a variable or passed as an argument to a function, where the procedure must refer programmatically to columns named in the variable/argument, and possibly includes updates, joins, groupings, calls to the `data.table` special objects `.I`, `.SD`, etc.; BUT one which is simpler, more elegant, shorter, or easier to design or implement or understand than the one above or others that require frequent `quote`-ing and `eval`-ing.

In particular please note that because the procedures can be fairly complex and involve repeatedly updating the `data.table` and then referencing the updated columns, the standard `lapply(.SD,...), ... .SDcols = ...` approach is usually not a workable substitute. Also replacing each call of `eval(a.column.name)` with `DT[[a.column.name]]` neither simplifies much nor works completely in general since that doesn't play nice with the other `data.table` operations, as far as I am aware.

I am aware of many workarounds for various use cases of variable column
names in `data.table`, including:

0. [Select / assign to data.table when variable names are stored in a character vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391950/variably-selecting-assigning-to-fields-in-a-data-table)
1. [Pass column name in data.table using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603890/pass-column-name-in-data-table-using-variable-in-r)
2. [Referring to data.table columns by names saved in variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617226/referring-to-data-table-columns-by-names-saved-in-variables)
3. [passing column names to data.table programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009669/passing-column-names-to-data-table-programmatically)
4. [Data.table meta-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790743/data-table-meta-programming)
5. [How to write a function that calls a function that calls data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837902/how-to-write-a-function-that-calls-a-function-that-calls-data-table)
6. [Using dynamic column names in `data.table`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937165/using-dynamic-column-names-in-data-table)
7. [Dynamic column names in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745169/dynamic-column-names-in-data-table-r)
8. [Assign multiple columns using := in data.table, by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680579/assign-multiple-columns-using-in-data-table-by-group)
9. [Setting column name in "group by" operation with data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525793/setting-column-name-in-group-by-operation-with-data-table)
10. [Summarizing multiple columns with data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513827/r-summarizing-multiple-columns-with-data-table)

and probably more I haven't referenced.

But: even if I learned all the tricks documented above to the point that I
never had to look them up to remind myself how to use them, I still would find
that working with column names that are passed as parameters to a function is
an extremely tedious task.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're looking for, as that example is far from minimal imo, but I normally use `get(varname)` on RHS (where `varname` is e.g. "var1" and not the quoted expression), and for LHS of `:=` you can simply do: `dt[, paste0(varname, '.rolling') := ...]`

Comment: Fair point, though it's difficult to know how "minimal" to make an example that is explicitly supposed to show that the question is only relevant when the procedure is complicated / involves many steps. Regarding `get()`, I considered it, but http://stackoverflow.com/a/12392269/241643 implied that it was sub-optimal. Is that no longer the case?

Comment: Theoretically, `get` can be suboptimal if you have a large number of columns, but in practice I find it much easier to use (which generally means faster overall runtime, when you include time spent writing/understanding/maintaining the code). It will likely be optimized to be as efficient as `eval(quote` at some point. I also remember an FR that was asking to implement the `.` as a function in `j`-expressions that would do the equivalent of `get`, but efficiently (it also included using `..` as a function to access variables outside of the local scope).

Comment: IIUC what you're asking for seems too general a function.. covering many features of data.table and handling any complex operation..

Comment: Start by reading http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html - your `quote.convert()` is just `as.name()`

Comment: Thanks--didn't realize you had written such a guide. As usual I'm enjoying making my way through it, + the other sections as well. [FWIW ggplot2 + related are also atop my list of life-changing R packages :) ] Anyway as far as I could tell, though, the equivalence you point out is the only improvement to the code above suggested by that document. Was I supposed to spot something else that could make the rest of the syntax in my example less tortured? Thanks!

Comment: @eddi's original response above, regarding RHS `get` and LHS `paste0` saved me hours of work.

Comment: @Philip if you are by any chance active user please review provided answers so we can have till highly upvoted and interesting question marked as answered.

Answer (score 14):

Problem you are describing is not strictly related to `data.table`.
Complex queries cannot be easily translated to code that machine can parse, thus we are not able to escape complexity in writing a query for complex operations.
You can try to imagine how to programmatically construct a query for the following `data.table` query using `dplyr` or *SQL*:

```r
DT[, c(f1(v1, v2, opt=TRUE),
       f2(v3, v4, v5, opt1=FALSE, opt2=TRUE),
       lapply(.SD, f3, opt1=TRUE, opt2=FALSE))
   , by=.(id1, id2)]
```

Assuming that all columns (`id1`, `id2`, `v1`...`v5`) or even options (`opt`, `opt1`, `opt2`) should be passed as variables.

Because of complexity in expression of queries I don't think you could easily accomplish requirement stated in your question:

> is simpler, more elegant, shorter, or easier to design or implement or understand than the one above or others that require frequent `quote`-ing and `eval`-ing.

Although, comparing to other programming languages, base R provides very useful tools to deal with such problems.

---

You already found suggestions to use `get`, `mget`, `DT[[col_name]]`, `parse`, `quote`, `eval`.

- As you mentioned `DT[[col_name]]` might not play well with `data.table` optimizations, thus is not that useful here.
- `parse` is probably the easiest way to construct complex queries as you can just operate on strings, but it doesn't provide basic language syntax validation. So you can ended up trying to parse a string that R parser does not accept. Additionally there is a security concern as presented in [2655#issuecomment-376781159](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2655#issuecomment-376781159).
- `get`/`mget` are the ones most commonly suggested to deal with such problems. `get` and `mget` are internally catch by `[.data.table` and translated to expected columns. So you are assuming your arbitrary complex query will be able to be decomposed by `[.data.table` and expected columns properly inputted.
- Since you asked this question few years back, the new feature - *dot-dot prefix* - is being rolled out in recently. You prefix variable name using dot-dot to refer to a variable outside of the scope of current data.table. Similarly as you refer parent directory in file system. Internals behind dot-dot will be quite similar to `get`, variables having prefix will be *de-referenced* inside of `[.data.table`.  . In future releases dot-dot prefix may allow calls like:

```r
col1="a"; col2="b"; col3="g"; col4="x"; col5="y"
DT[..col4==..col5, .(s1=sum(..col1), s2=sum(..col2)), by=..col3]
```

- Personally I prefer `quote` and `eval` instead. `quote` and `eval` is interpreted almost as written by hand from scratch. This method does not rely on `data.table` abilities to manage references to columns. We can expect all optimizations to work the same way as if you would write those queries by hand. I found it also easier to debug as at any point you can just print quoted expression to see what is actually passed to `data.table` query. Additionally there is a less space for bugs to occur. Constructing complex queries using R language object is sometimes tricky, it is easy to wrap the procedure into function so it can be applied in different use cases and easily re-used. Important to note that this method is independent from `data.table`. It uses R language constructs. You can find more information about that in official [R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html) in *Computing on the language* chapter.
- What else?

  - I submitted proposal of a new concept called *macro* in [#1579](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1579). In short it is a wrapper on `DT[eval(qi), eval(qj), eval(qby)]` so you still have to operate on R language objects. You are welcome to put your comment there.
  - Recently I proposed another approach for metaprogramming interface in [PR#4304](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4304). In short it plugs base R `substitute` functionality into `[.data.table` using new argument `env`.

---

Going to the example. Below I will show two ways to solve it. First one will use base R metaprogramming, second one will use metaprogramming for data.table proposed in [PR#4304](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4304) (see above).

- Base R computing on the language

I will wrap all logic into `do_vars` function. Calling `do_vars(donot=TRUE)` will print expressions to be computed on `data.table` instead of `eval` them. Below code should be run just after the OP code.

```r
expected = copy(new.table)
new.table = the.table[, list(asofdate=seq(from=ymd((year)*10^4+101), length.out=12, by="1 month")), by=year]

do_vars = function(x, y, vars, donot=FALSE) {
  name.suffix = function(x, suffix) as.name(paste(x, suffix, sep="."))
  do_var = function(var, x, y) {
    substitute({
      x[, .anntot := y[, rep(.var, each=12)]]
      x[, .monthly := y[, rep(.var/12, each=12)]]
      x[, .rolling := rollapply(.monthly, mean, width=12, fill=c(head(.monthly,1), tail(.monthly,1)))]
      x[, .scaled := .anntot/sum(.rolling)*.rolling, by=year]
    }, list(
      .var=as.name(var),
      .anntot=name.suffix(var, "annual.total"),
      .monthly=name.suffix(var, "monthly"),
      .rolling=name.suffix(var, "rolling"),
      .scaled=name.suffix(var, "scaled")
    ))
  }
  ql = lapply(setNames(nm=vars), do_var, x, y)
  if (donot) return(ql)
  lapply(ql, eval.parent)
  invisible(x)
}
do_vars(new.table, the.table, c("var1","var2","var3"))
all.equal(expected, new.table)
#[1] TRUE
```

we can preview queries

```r
do_vars(new.table, the.table, c("var1","var2","var3"), donot=TRUE)
#$var1
#{
#    x[, `:=`(var1.annual.total, y[, rep(var1, each = 12)])]
#    x[, `:=`(var1.monthly, y[, rep(var1/12, each = 12)])]
#    x[, `:=`(var1.rolling, rollapply(var1.monthly, mean, width = 12, 
#        fill = c(head(var1.monthly, 1), tail(var1.monthly, 1))))]
#    x[, `:=`(var1.scaled, var1.annual.total/sum(var1.rolling) * 
#        var1.rolling), by = year]
#}
#
#$var2
#{
#    x[, `:=`(var2.annual.total, y[, rep(var2, each = 12)])]
#    x[, `:=`(var2.monthly, y[, rep(var2/12, each = 12)])]
#    x[, `:=`(var2.rolling, rollapply(var2.monthly, mean, width = 12, 
#        fill = c(head(var2.monthly, 1), tail(var2.monthly, 1))))]
#    x[, `:=`(var2.scaled, var2.annual.total/sum(var2.rolling) * 
#        var2.rolling), by = year]
#}
#
#$var3
#{
#    x[, `:=`(var3.annual.total, y[, rep(var3, each = 12)])]
#    x[, `:=`(var3.monthly, y[, rep(var3/12, each = 12)])]
#    x[, `:=`(var3.rolling, rollapply(var3.monthly, mean, width = 12, 
#        fill = c(head(var3.monthly, 1), tail(var3.monthly, 1))))]
#    x[, `:=`(var3.scaled, var3.annual.total/sum(var3.rolling) * 
#        var3.rolling), by = year]
#}
#
```

- Proposed data.table metaprogramming

```r
expected = copy(new.table)
new.table = the.table[, list(asofdate=seq(from=ymd((year)*10^4+101), length.out=12, by="1 month")), by=year]

name.suffix = function(x, suffix) as.name(paste(x, suffix, sep="."))
do_var2 = function(var, x, y) {
  x[, .anntot := y[, rep(.var, each=12)],
    env = list(
      .anntot = name.suffix(var, "annual.total"),
      .var = var
    )]
  x[, .monthly := y[, rep(.var/12, each=12)],
    env = list(
      .monthly = name.suffix(var, "monthly"),
      .var = var
    )]
  x[, .rolling := rollapply(.monthly, mean, width=12, fill=c(head(.monthly,1), tail(.monthly,1))),
    env = list(
      .rolling = name.suffix(var, "rolling"),
      .monthly = name.suffix(var, "monthly")
    )]
  x[, .scaled := .anntot/sum(.rolling)*.rolling, by=year,
    env = list(
      .scaled = name.suffix(var, "scaled"),
      .anntot = name.suffix(var, "annual.total"),
      .rolling = name.suffix(var, "rolling")
    )]
  TRUE
}

sapply(setNames(nm=var.names), do_var2, new.table, the.table)
#var1 var2 var3 
#TRUE TRUE TRUE 
all.equal(expected, new.table)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Data and updated OP code

```r
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)

the.table <- data.table(year=1991:1996,var1=floor(runif(6,400,1400)))
the.table[,`:=`(var2=var1/floor(runif(6,2,5)),
                var3=var1/floor(runif(6,2,5)))]

# Replicate data across months
new.table <- the.table[, list(asofdate=seq(from=ymd((year)*10^4+101),
                                           length.out=12,
                                           by="1 month")),by=year]

# Do a complicated procedure to each variable in some group.
var.names <- c("var1","var2","var3")

for(varname in var.names) {
  #As suggested in an answer to Link 3 above
  #Convert the column name to a 'quote' object
  quote.convert <- function(x) eval(parse(text=paste0('quote(',x,')')))
  
  #Do this for every column name I'll need
  varname <- quote.convert(varname)
  anntot <- quote.convert(paste0(varname,".annual.total"))
  monthly <- quote.convert(paste0(varname,".monthly"))
  rolling <- quote.convert(paste0(varname,".rolling"))
  scaled <- quote.convert(paste0(varname,".scaled"))
  
  #Perform the relevant tasks, using eval()
  #around every variable columnname I may want
  new.table[,paste0(varname,".annual.total"):=
              the.table[,rep(eval(varname),each=12)]]
  new.table[,paste0(varname,".monthly"):=
              the.table[,rep(eval(varname)/12,each=12)]]
  new.table[,paste0(varname,".rolling"):=
              rollapply(eval(monthly),mean,width=12,
                        fill=c(head(eval(monthly),1),
                               tail(eval(monthly),1)))]
  new.table[,paste0(varname,".scaled"):=
              eval(anntot)/sum(eval(rolling))*eval(rolling),
            by=year]
}
```

Comment: Hi @jangorecki! Perhaps update this nice answer with a pointer to [data.table v1.14.1`devel`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#new-features), item 10: "A new interface for programming on data.table has been added" Cheers

Comment: Hi @jangorecki, could you explain why you used `setNames(nm=var.names)` instead of just `var.names` in 

    `sapply(setNames(nm=var.names), do_var2, new.table, the.table)`

Comment: @Paul afair so the result of sapply is named, and then output columns are named rather than V1... You can change and check if it works and give same names

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the question.  Your original approach goes a long way towards solving most of the issues.

Here I've tweaked the quoting function slightly, and changed the approach to parse and evaluate the entire RHS expression as a string instead of the individual variables.

The reasoning being:

- You probably don't want to be repeating yourself by declaring every variable you need to use at the start of the loop.
- Strings will scale better since they can be generated programmatically.  I've added an example below that calculates row-wise percentages to illustrate this.

---

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)

set.seed(1)
the.table <- data.table(year=1991:1996,var1=floor(runif(6,400,1400)))
the.table[,`:=`(var2=var1/floor(runif(6,2,5)),
                var3=var1/floor(runif(6,2,5)))]

# Replicate data across months
new.table <- the.table[, list(asofdate=seq(from=ymd((year)*10^4+101),
                                           length.out=12,
                                           by="1 month")),by=year]
# function to paste, parse & evaluate arguments
evalp <- function(..., envir=parent.frame()) {eval(parse(text=paste0(...)), envir=envir)}

# Do a complicated procedure to each variable in some group.
var.names <- c("var1","var2","var3")

for(varname in var.names) {

  # 1. For LHS, use paste0 to generate new column name as string (from @eddi's comment)
  # 2. For RHS, use evalp
  new.table[, paste0(varname, '.annual.total') := evalp(
    'the.table[,rep(', varname, ',each=12)]'
  )]

  new.table[, paste0(varname, '.monthly') := evalp(
    'the.table[,rep(', varname, '/12,each=12)]'
  )]

  # Need to add envir=.SD when working within the table
  new.table[, paste0(varname, '.rolling') := evalp(
    'rollapply(',varname, '.monthly,mean,width=12, 
        fill=c(head(', varname, '.monthly,1), tail(', varname, '.monthly,1)))'
    , envir=.SD
  )]

  new.table[,paste0(varname, '.scaled'):= evalp(
      varname, '.annual.total / sum(', varname, '.rolling) * ', varname, '.rolling'
      , envir=.SD
    )
    ,by=year
  ]

  # Since we're working with strings, more freedom 
  # to work programmatically
  new.table[, paste0(varname, '.row.percent') := evalp(
    'the.table[,rep(', varname, '/ (', paste(var.names, collapse='+'), '), each=12)]'
  )]
}
```

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting this; maybe they could offer some feedback? My thoughts: 1. this "works" in the sense of being scalable, 2. it resembles some approaches I've used when for lack of a better way to get R to repeat over what I want I've essentially had to write code that writes R code (which this is equivalent to modulo some details), and 3. therefore it's dangerous / non-standard / not super elegant. However, so far no one has offered a canonical, effective approach that doesn't use some similar-in-spirit hack. +1 'til then, but happy to hear from anyone with a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to do this in data.table thinking "this isn't so bad"... but after an embarrassing length of time, I gave up. Matt says something like 'do in pieces then join', but I couldn't figure out elegant ways to do these pieces, especially because the last one depends on previous steps.

I have to say, this is a pretty brilliantly constructed question, and I too encounter similar issues frequently.  I love data.table, but I still struggle sometimes.  I don't know if I'm struggling with data.table or the complexity of the problem.

Here is the incomplete approach I've taken.

Realistically I can imagine that in a normal process you would have more intermediate variables stored that would be useful for calculating these values.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

## Example yearly data
set.seed(27)
DT <- data.table(year=1991:1996,
                 var1=floor(runif(6,400,1400)))
DT[ , var2 := var1 / floor(runif(6,2,5))]
DT[ , var3 := var1 / floor(runif(6,2,5))]
setkeyv(DT,colnames(DT)[1])
DT

## Convenience function
nonkey <- function(dt){colnames(dt)[!colnames(dt)%in%key(dt)]}

## Annual data expressed monthly
NewDT <- DT[, j=list(asofdate=as.IDate(paste(year, 1:12, 1, sep="-"))), by=year]
setkeyv(NewDT, colnames(NewDT)[1:2])

## Create annual data
NewDT_Annual <- NewDT[DT]
setnames(NewDT_Annual, 
         nonkey(NewDT_Annual), 
         paste0(nonkey(NewDT_Annual), ".annual.total"))

## Compute monthly data
NewDT_Monthly <- NewDT[DT[ , .SD / 12, keyby=list(year)]]
setnames(NewDT_Monthly, 
         nonkey(NewDT_Monthly), 
         paste0(nonkey(NewDT_Monthly), ".monthly"))

## Compute rolling stats
NewDT_roll <- NewDT_Monthly[j = lapply(.SD, rollapply, mean, width=12, 
                                       fill=c(.SD[1],tail(.SD, 1))),
                            .SDcols=nonkey(NewDT_Monthly)]
NewDT_roll <- cbind(NewDT_Monthly[,1:2,with=F], NewDT_roll)
setkeyv(NewDT_roll, colnames(NewDT_roll)[1:2])
setnames(NewDT_roll, 
         nonkey(NewDT_roll), 
         gsub(".monthly$",".rolling",nonkey(NewDT_roll)))

## Compute normalized values

## Compute "adjustment" table which is 
## total of each variable, by year for rolling
## divided by
## original annual totals

## merge "adjustment values" in with monthly data, and then 
## make a modified data.table which is each varaible * annual adjustment factor

## Merge everything
NewDT_Combined <- NewDT_Annual[NewDT_roll][NewDT_Monthly]
```

Comment: This is interesting; thanks. I've just taken the time to work through it and understand the workflow. It is not natural to me but I understand the idea. The thing that I'm not sure about is whether it feels unnatural simply because it is new/foreign to my way of using `data.table` or because it actually is tortuous/truly unnatural. Granted, it may be that there just is no natural way to do what I(/we) are trying to do. I hope some more people might leave their thoughts; if that doesn't happen for a while I'll accept or maybe after bounty. Thanks!

Comment: Phillip, I really appreciate your comments. In my experience DT has been very unnatural to adopt but well worth it; much like using R over Excel. I see examples on SO that blow my mind (usually from Matt and Arun), and I wonder if I'm doing it right at all.

Comment: Also, I don't think you should accept this as an answer as is.