# r - passing variables as data.table column names

Tags: r, data.table

The more I use it, the more `data.table` is replacing `dplyr` as my 'goto' package as the speed it offers is a big plus.

**Question**

Can you pass variables to `i` in data.table (`dt[i,j]`) withouth creating an `expression`?

**Example**

Given a data.table:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(val1 = c(1,2,3),
                 val2 = c(3,2,1))
```

I would like to evalulate:

```
dt[(val1 > val2)]
```

but using a variable to reference the column names. For example,

```
myCol <- c("val1", "val2")  ## vector of column names
```

I've read a [lots of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833247/how-can-one-work-fully-generically-in-data-table-in-r-with-column-names-in-varia) that show ways of doing this with expressions:

```
## create an expression to evaluate
expr <- parse(text = paste0(myCol[1], " > ", myCol[2]))

## evaluate expression
dt[(eval(expr))]

   val1 val2
1:    3    1
```

But I was wondering if there is a more 'direct' way to do this that I've missed, something akin to:

```
dt[(myCol[1] > myCol[2])]
```

Or is the `expression` route the way this should be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use `eval(as.name(..`

```
dt[eval(as.name(myCol[1]))> eval(as.name(myCol[2]))]
```

Or we can specify it in the `.SDcols`

```
dt[dt[, .I[.SD[[1]]> .SD[[2]]], .SDcols= myCol]]
```

Or an option using `get` by @thelatemail

```
dt[get(myCol[1]) > get(myCol[2])]
```

If there are only two elements, we can also use `Reduce` with `mget` (a slight variation of @thelatemail's answer)

```
dt[Reduce('>', mget(myCol))]
```

Comment: Would it be correct to say that `eval(as.name(...)) == get()`  ?

Comment: @tospig This [link](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html) would give more ideas.