# data.table: why is it not always possible to pass column names directly?

Tags: r, data.table

Getting started with the `data.table` package (author/maintainer: Matt Dowle). Great package. I love that I can write `dt[, x1]` instead of, say, `dt[, dt$x1]` or `df["x1"]`, for a data.table `dt`, a column name `x1`,  a data.frame `df`. Being able to pass column names directly is an attractive feature of data.table. But dispensing with quotes around a column name, (writing `x1` instead of `"x1"`) is not always feasible. Why?

*Programming Question*: Are there any reasons why it is not always possible to pass a vector of column names directly to a data.table or to the helper functions provided by the package? For instance, the `subset`, `merge`, and `melt` functions have been rewritten for the data.table package, but while `subset` can handle column names directly, `merge` and `melt` cannot (see below).

To clarify, my question is not *when* or *how* but *why*. There are excellent related discussions with very useful tips, e.g. [Select / assign to data.table variables which names are stored in a character vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391950/variably-selecting-assigning-to-fields-in-a-data-table) and [r - passing variables as data.table column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33006221/r-passing-variables-as-data-table-column-names) . With these answers and a bit of trial and error, I'm able to find my way around the quote/unquote distinctions. My question is why is it not currently possible to always dispense with quotes around column names: is there a design to it? is it a transitional situation? are there programming difficulties?

Below, I give some examples and number the examples for clarity.

```
# load the package
library("data.table") # because I cannot do install.packages(data.table)!!
```

## **(i)**

```
# make a data.table
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(id = 1:5, x1 = 1:5, x2 = 5:1, x3 = round(runif(5, 1, 5), 0), key = "id")
```

I can define the data.table with either `id = 1:10` or `"id" = 1:10`, but I must define the key with `key = "id"`  as `key = id` does not work:

```
dt <- data.table(id = 1:5, x1 = 1:5, x2 = 5:1, x3 = round(runif(5, 1, 5), 0), key = id)
##Error in data.table(id = 1:5, x1 = 1:5, x2 = 5:1, x3 = round(runif(5,  : 
##  object 'id' not found
```

You'd think finding 'id' should be rather easy for a key if it were looking for it among the column names? Would it be programmatically sound to be allowed to drop the quotes on the RHS of `key`?

## **(ii)**

I can `subset` with a vector of columns or with a vector of column names:

```
subset(dt, select = c(x1, x3))
##   x1 x3
##1:  1  2
##2:  2  2
##3:  3  3
##4:  4  5
##5:  5  2

subset(dt, select = c("x1", "x3"))
##   x1 x3
##1:  1  2
##2:  2  2
##3:  3  3
##4:  4  5
##5:  5  2
```

Nice and flexible.

## **(iii)**

I can `merge` with a vector of column names:

```
merge(dt, dt, by = c("x1", "x2"))
##       id x1 x2 x3
##1:  1  1  5  2
##2:  2  2  4  2
##3:  3  3  3  3
##4:  4  4  2  5
##5:  5  5  1  2
```

(silly example that was!) but not with a vector of the columns:

```
merge(dt, dt, by = c(x1, x2))
##Error in merge.data.table(dt, dt, by = c(x1, x2)) : object 'x1' not found
```

Is there something about `merge` that prevents it from accepting a vector of columns the way `subset` does?

## **(iv)**

Likewise, `melt` must take quoted column names (or integers corresponding to the column numbers).

The help description is specific that `melt` accepts "character vectors", while the help for `merge` simply states "vectors of column names," but clearly with `merge` as with `melt` character vectors are expected.

## **(v)**

In the case of the `j` argument, quoting variable names is not usually the correct approach:

```
# Good:
dt[, .(x1, x2)]
##   x1 x2
##1:  1  5
##2:  2  4
##3:  3  3
##4:  4  2
##5:  5  1

# Bad 
dt[, .("x1", "x2")]
##   V1 V2
##1: x1 x2
# This feature is well documented in the FAQs
# FAQ 2.3: "I'm using c() in the j and getting strange results."
```

Note to the reader not at all familiar with `data.tables` that `.()` is a shorthand for `list()` and that `dt[, c(x1, x2)]` is unlikely to be the desired command here -- the `j` argument of `dt[i, j]` very much expects a list.

## **(vi)**

However, within the `j` argument of `dt[i, j]`, the LHS of the "assignment by reference" operator `:=` has a confusing convention.

If the LHS is a single column, it may be passed without quotes. But if it has multiple columns, they must be passed as a vector of quoted column names. The manual only says "a vector of column names", but experimentation suggests they must be quoted:

```
# Good:
dt[, c("x1", "x2") := NULL][]
##   id x3
##1:  1  2
##2:  2  2
##3:  3  3
##4:  4  5
##5:  5  2

# Bad:
dt[, c(x1, x2) := NULL]
##Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x1' not found
```

The error message is not particularly enlightening.  But now I remember the FAQ's advice, "If 2 or more columns are required, use list() or .() instead." Silly me, `c(x1, x2)` couldn't work because there is no way to tell where `x1` ends and `x2` starts. However, `.(x1, x2)` could work, couldn't it?

```
# Bad:
dt[, .(x1, x2) := NULL]
##Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x1' not found
```

No, all things considered, the LHS of `:=` expects a vector of *quoted* column names. The manual ought to be updated or, if feasible, `data.table` extended to accept lists of unquoted columns on the LHS.

Oh wait. To delete multiple column names, can I pass a list of quoted names to LHS? No. Lists are usually desirable, but not on the LHS of `:=`. The error message is clear:

```
# Bad:
dt[, .("x1", "x2") := NULL][]
##Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(.("x1", "x2"), NULL)) : 
##  LHS of := must be a symbol, or an atomic vector (column names or positions).
```

## **(vii)**

The `i` argument of `dt[i]` is also designed to accept unquoted columns, i.e. an "expression of column names"

```
dt[.(x1, x2)]
##   id x1 x2 x3 V2
##1:  1  1  5  2  5
##2:  2  2  4  2  4
##3:  3  3  3  3  3
##4:  4  4  2  5  2
##5:  5  5  1  2  1
```

Note that if the idea was to subset the two columns `x1` and `x2`, that ought to be done inside the `j` argument, i.e. `dt[,.(x1, x2)]`

```
dt[.("x1", "x2")]
##Error in bmerge(i, x, leftcols, rightcols, io, xo, roll, rollends, nomatch,  : 
##  typeof x.id (integer) != typeof i.V1 (character)

dt[c(x1, x2)]
##id x1 x2 x3
## 1:  1  1  5  2
## 2:  2  2  4  2
## 3:  3  3  3  3
## 4:  4  4  2  5
## 5:  5  5  1  2
## 6:  5  5  1  2
## 7:  4  4  2  5
## 8:  3  3  3  3
## 9:  2  2  4  2
##10:  1  1  5  2

dt[c("x1", "x2")]
##Error in bmerge(i, x, leftcols, rightcols, io, xo, roll, rollends, nomatch,  : 
##  typeof x.id (integer) != typeof i.V1 (character)
```

I have shown here several situations where columns must be passed as `x1` or as `"x1"` and situations where both can be done. These differences can cause confusion to new users like me. I suspect there is more than one reason for these two approaches to coexist. I'd appreciate if someone could clarify the matter, for some of my examples if not for all of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(i), (iii) and (iv) sound like Feature Requests (FRs); see [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/) (so, yes, it's partly due to `data.table` not having reached full maturity).

As to (v) you said "`dt[, c(x1, x2)]` is unlikely to be the desired command here", but in fact I have seen situations where that sort of use of `c` within `j` is what I'm after. Situations like (v) are what the `with` argument of `[.data.table` are for.

On (vi) and elsewhere, you suggest "The manual only says 'a vector of column names', but experimentation suggests they must be quoted"; but I think this is unambiguous. A vector of column names means a `character` vector, which `c(x1,x2)` is not, unless `x1` and `x2` are somewhere defined as `character` vectors themselves. You can also add a FR for documentation on GitHub.

I'm not sure what you're after in (vii), but in `i`, vectors of names are used for joins or keyed subsets (also a form of join); see the [vignette on fast subsetting](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html).

Comment: Thanks Michael. This clarifies. I thought a "vector of column names" was intended to refer to ``c(x1, x2)`` (where ``x1`` and ``x2`` are not character vectors) and that for this reason the expression "character vector" was used for ``c("x1", "x2")``, but you are saying that "vector of column names" and "character vector" are synonyms. I see now that a column name is always a character vector, so that my interpretation of "vector of column names" was incorrect. What do you call this object ``c(x1, x2)`` ?

Comment: I think it's important to recognize that some of this is vestigal -- nothing that I can think of in base R can handle unquoted column names (without the crutch of the `with` function) like `data.table` can, so quoted column names is the norm, and `data.table` has done a great job (IMO) of pushing towards more natural syntax like you've got in mind. Perhaps check out some background reading on how evaluation happens in R, perhaps a chapter in Hadley's book ([1](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html), [2](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html))

Comment: More to your point, `c(x1, x2)` **c**oncatenates the objects `x1` and `x2` (so it's just another vector of type equal to the most-generic type of `x1` and `x2`--e.g., if `x1` is `numeric` and `x2` `integer`, `c(x1,x2)` is `numeric`); if evaluated within the scope of another object (`list`, `data.frame`, `data.table`, etc.), these objects are column names or element names; otherwise (simplifying a bit), R uses what's found in the global environment. Characters (i.e., non-alphanumerics) are _always_ interpreted as variable names by R.

Comment: Excellent reference to Hadley's book. Really helps.

Comment: @PatrickT happy to help. I too was a convert to R that started with `data.table`, so it can take some practice to get used to how base R works when you're used to the beauty of `data.table`, which is itself constantly improving.