# How to use data.table within functions and loops?

Tags: r, function, loops, data.table, dplyr

While assessing the utility of `data.table` (vs. `dplyr`), a critical factor is the ability to use it within functions and loops.
For this, I've modified the code snippet used in this post: [data.table vs dplyr: can one do something well the other can't or does poorly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435339/data-table-vs-dplyr-can-one-do-something-well-the-other-cant-or-does-poorly) so that, instead of  hard-coded dataset variables names ("cut" and "price" variables of "diamonds" dataset), it becomes dataset-agnostic - cut-n-paste ready for the use inside any function or a loop (when we don't know column names in advance).

This is the original code:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(ggplot2::diamonds)
dt[cut != "Fair", .(mean(price),.N), by = cut]
```

This is its dataset-agnostic equivalent:

```
dt <- data.table(diamonds)
nVarGroup <- 2 #"cut"
nVarMeans <- 7 #"price"

strGroupConditions <- levels(dt[[nVarGroup]])[-1] # "Good" "Very Good" "Premium" "Ideal" 
strVarGroup <- names(dt)[nVarGroup]
strVarMeans <- names(dt)[nVarMeans]
qAction <- quote(mean(get(strVarMeans))) #! w/o get() it does not work! 
qGroup <- quote(get(strVarGroup) %in% strGroupConditions) #! w/o get() it does not work! 
dt[eval(qGroup), .(eval(qAction), .N), by = strVarGroup]
```

Note (Thanks to reply below): if you need to change variable value by reference, you need to use `()`, not `get()`, as shown below:

```
strVarToBeReplaced <- names(dt)[1]
dt[eval(qGroup), (strVarToBeReplaced) := eval(qAction), by = strGroup][]
```

Now: you can cut-n-paste the following code for all your looping needs:

```
for(nVarGroup in 2:4)       # Grouped by several categorical values...
  for(nVarMeans in 5:10) {  # ... get means of all numerical parameters
    strGroupConditions <- levels(dt[[nVarGroup]])[-1] 
    strVarGroup <- names(dt)[nVarGroup]
    strVarMeans <- names(dt)[nVarMeans]
    qAction  <- quote(mean(get(strVarMeans))) 
    qGroup <- quote(get(strVarGroup) %in% strGroupConditions) 
    p <- dt[eval(qGroup), .(AVE=eval(qAction), COUNT=.N), by = strVarGroup]

    print(sprintf("nVaGroup=%s, nVarMeans=%s: ", strVarGroup, strVarMeans))
    print(p)
  }
```

My first question:
The code above, while enabling the required functional/looping needs, appears quite convoluted. - It uses different multiple (possibly non-consistent) non-intuitive tricks such combination of `()`, `get()`, `quote()`/`eval()`, `[[]]`). Seems too many for a such straightforward need...

**Is there another better way of accessing and modifying data.tables values in loops?** Perhaps with `on=`,  `lapply`/`.SD`/`.SDcols`?

Please share your ideas below. This discussion aims to supplement and consolidate related bits from other posts (such as listed here: [How can one work fully generically in data.table in R with column names in variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833247/how-can-one-work-fully-generically-in-data-table-in-r-with-column-names-in-varia)). Eventually, it would be great  to create a dedicated vignette for using `data.table` within `functions` and `loops`.

The second question:
**Is dplyr easier for this purpose?** - For this question however, I've set a separate post: [Is dplyr easier than data.table to be used within functions and loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42398867/how-to-use-dplyr-within-functions-and-loops).

Comment: If you are willing to forgo the dupe or bad column names and/or clean them up first, I guess it's easier.

Comment: suggestion:it would be better to post a new qn than to change the previous qn because the new one is not going to get much visibility. try `dt[eval(qGroup), (strVarToBeReplaced) := 999, by = strGroup][]` instead

Comment: I don't get your question. How is your "dataset-agnostic" code more general than just using data.table directly?

Comment: You mentioned `[[]]` not being described well in the `data.table` vignettes. However, `DT[["v"]]` is included in the Examples section of `?data.table`, "select columns the data.frame way" with the comment "same as DT[, v] but much faster". So, this seems this to be the preferred way to go

Comment: The question is not about the absence of documentation (e.g . on [[]]), but on developing the best possible way of working with data.tables in dataset-agnostic sense - so that any codes provided on stackoverflow.com can be easily reused by all of us - by simply cut-n-paste, without the need to figure out how to replace "hard coded" variable names with our variables.      Imagine -  how easier it would be  to develop collectively open-source libraries using each other's codes, if we don't use "hard-coded' name variables in our examples, but rather always use dataset-agnostic codes... Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the most `data.table`-like or the fastest solution but I would streamline the code in this *particular* loop as follows:

```
for(nVarGroup in 2:4) {      # Grouped by several categorical values...
  for(nVarMeans in 5:10) {  # ... get means of all numerical parameters
    strGroupConditions <- levels(dt[[nVarGroup]])[-1] 
    strVarGroup <- names(dt)[nVarGroup]
    strVarMeans <- names(dt)[nVarMeans]
    # qAction <- quote(mean(get(strVarMeans)))
    # qGroup <- quote(get(strVarGroup) %in% strGroupConditions)
    # p <- dt[eval(qGroup), .(AVE = eval(qAction), COUNT = .N), by = strVarGroup]
    setkeyv(dt, strVarGroup)
    p <- dt[strGroupConditions, .(AVE = lapply(.SD, mean), COUNT = .N), by = strVarGroup, 
            .SDcols = strVarMeans]

    print(sprintf("nVaGroup = %s, nVarMeans = %s", strVarGroup, strVarMeans))
    print(p)
  }
}
```

I've left the old code as comment for reference.

`qAction` is replaced by using `lapply(.SD, mean)` together with the `.SDcols` parameter.

`qGroup` for subsetting rows is replaced by the combination of setting a key and providing the vector of desired values as `i` parameter.

---

In case of a more complex subsetting expression I would try use non-equi (or conditional) joins using the `on=` syntax.

Or, follow [Matt Dowle's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12392269/3817004) to create *one* expression to be evaluated, "similar to constructing a dynamic SQL statement to send to a server".

Matt suggested to create a helper function

```
EVAL <- function(...) eval(parse(text = paste0(...)), envir = parent.frame(2))
```

which can be combined with the "quasi-perl type string interpolation of `fn$` from the `gsubfn` package to improve the readability of the EVAL solution" as [suggested by G. Grothendieck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391950/select-assign-to-data-table-variables-which-names-are-stored-in-a-character-ve#comment19897254_12392269).

With this, the code for the loop becomes eventually:

```
EVAL <- function(...) eval(parse(text = paste0(...)), envir = parent.frame(2))
library(gsubfn)

for(nVarGroup in 2:4) {      # Grouped by several categorical values...
  for(nVarMeans in 5:10) {  # ... get means of all numerical parameters
    strGroupConditions = levels(dt[[nVarGroup]])[-1] 
    strVarGroup = names(dt)[nVarGroup]
    strVarMeans = names(dt)[nVarMeans]
    p <- fn$EVAL("dt[$strVarGroup %in% strGroupConditions, .(AVE=mean($strVarMeans), COUNT=.N), by = strVarGroup]" )

    print(sprintf("nVaGroup = %s, nVarMeans = %s", strVarGroup, strVarMeans))
    print(p)
  }
}
```

Now, the `data.table` statement looks pretty much like a "native" statement except that `$strVarGroup` and `$strVarMeans` is used where the contents of variables is referenced.

---

With version 1.1.0 (CRAN release on 2016-08-19), the `stringr` package has gained a string interpolation function `str_interp()` which is an alternative to the `gsubfn` package here.

With `str_interp()`, the central statement in the for loop would become

```
p <- EVAL(stringr::str_interp(
  "dt[${strVarGroup} %in% strGroupConditions, .(AVE=mean(${strVarMeans}), COUNT=.N), by = strVarGroup]"
  ))
```

and the call to `library(gsubfn)` could be removed.

Answer (score 7):

The OP has asked for a *dataset-agnostic equivalent* for grouping and aggregating.

With [development version 1.10.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md), `data.table` has gained new *Grouping Sets* functions: `rollup()`, `cube()`, and `groupingsets()` which allow aggregation on various grouping levels at once producing sub-totals and grand total.

The added level of abstraction can be used for a *dataset-agnostic* approach. The subtotals which are computed using a double nested `for` loop in OP's example can be produced as well by

```
library(data.table) # version 1.10.5 required
dt = data.table(ggplot2::diamonds)
groupingsets(dt, c(lapply(.SD, mean), list(COUNT = .N)), 
     by = names(dt)[2:4], .SDcols = 5:10, id = FALSE,
     sets = as.list(names(dt)[2:4]))
```

> ```
>           cut color clarity    depth    table    price        x        y        z COUNT
>  1:     Ideal    NA      NA 61.70940 55.95167 3457.542 5.507451 5.520080 3.401448 21551
>  2:   Premium    NA      NA 61.26467 58.74610 4584.258 5.973887 5.944879 3.647124 13791
>  3:      Good    NA      NA 62.36588 58.69464 3928.864 5.838785 5.850744 3.639507  4906
>  4: Very Good    NA      NA 61.81828 57.95615 3981.760 5.740696 5.770026 3.559801 12082
>  5:      Fair    NA      NA 64.04168 59.05379 4358.758 6.246894 6.182652 3.982770  1610
>  6:        NA     E      NA 61.66209 57.49120 3076.752 5.411580 5.419029 3.340689  9797
>  7:        NA     I      NA 61.84639 57.57728 5091.875 6.222826 6.222730 3.845411  5422
>  8:        NA     J      NA 61.88722 57.81239 5323.818 6.519338 6.518105 4.033251  2808
>  9:        NA     H      NA 61.83685 57.51781 4486.669 5.983335 5.984815 3.695965  8304
> 10:        NA     F      NA 61.69458 57.43354 3724.886 5.614961 5.619456 3.464446  9542
> 11:        NA     G      NA 61.75711 57.28863 3999.136 5.677543 5.680192 3.505021 11292
> 12:        NA     D      NA 61.69813 57.40459 3169.954 5.417051 5.421128 3.342827  6775
> 13:        NA    NA     SI2 61.77217 57.92718 5063.029 6.401370 6.397826 3.948478  9194
> 14:        NA    NA     SI1 61.85304 57.66254 3996.001 5.888383 5.888256 3.639845 13065
> 15:        NA    NA     VS1 61.66746 57.31515 3839.455 5.572178 5.581828 3.441007  8171
> 16:        NA    NA     VS2 61.72442 57.41740 3924.989 5.657709 5.658859 3.491478 12258
> 17:        NA    NA    VVS2 61.66378 57.02499 3283.737 5.218454 5.232118 3.221465  5066
> 18:        NA    NA    VVS1 61.62465 56.88446 2523.115 4.960364 4.975075 3.061294  3655
> 19:        NA    NA      I1 62.73428 58.30378 3924.169 6.761093 6.709379 4.207908   741
> 20:        NA    NA      IF 61.51061 56.50721 2864.839 4.968402 4.989827 3.061659  1790
> ```

So, we do not have to know the names of the columns. However, we have to specify which columns to group by and which columns to aggregate.