# How to use a complicated result from paste inside data.table's "i" part?

Tags: r, data.table

Say I have a data table and I want to calculate a new variable based on several conditions of the old variables like this:

```
library(data.table)
test <- data.table(a = c(1,1,0), b = c(0,1,0), c = c(1,1,1))

test[a==1 & b==1 & c==1,test2:=1]
```

But I actually have many more conditions (all combinations of the different variables) which also have a different length. I draw those from a list such as:

```
conditions<-list(c("a","b","c"), c("b","c"))
```

and then I want to loop through that list and build a character vector like this (with which I want to do something before deleting it and going to the next element of the list):

```
mystring <- paste0(paste0(conditions[[1]], collapse = "==1 & "), "==1")
```

But how can I use "mystring" inside the `data.table`? as.function() or get() or  eval() don't seem to work. Something like:

```
test[mystring,test3:=1]
```

is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Not clear what "mychars" is.

Comment: mystring, sorry, was an earlier version

Comment: Ok,, well there's `test[eval(parse(text = mystring)), test3 := 1]`, but it's pretty strongly discouraged in data.table and R generally to fiddle with strings as code. Besides, data.table has better ways of handling this sort of filter-and-update stuff. You might want to look through its vignettes.

Comment: And also similar with bquote. Sadly, R's not lispy enough to write easy-to-understand macros, so it's generally discouraged unless you really need it.

`myExp = parse(text=mystring)
eval(bquote(test[.(myExp), test3 := 1]))`

Comment: Perhaps, Matt Dowle's `EVAL` approach [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42433456/3817004) is what you are looking for?  It creates an expression to be evaluated, "similar to constructing a dynamic SQL statement to send to a server".

Comment: @UweBlock interesting yet still manipulating strings to build an expression. What I'd really want is a defmacro for R to manipulate symbols to build an expression. The problem is that R's syntax (along with other curly brace languages) is too complex to make that an easy task to build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the given use case, you may use join with `on =` to achieve the desired goal without having to create and evaluate complex strings of conditions.

Instead of

```
test[a==1 & b==1 & c==1, test2 := 1][]
```

we can write

```
test[.(1, 1, 1), on = c("a", "b", "c"), test2 := 1][]
#   a b c test2
#1: 1 0 1    NA
#2: 1 1 1     1
#3: 0 0 1    NA
```

Now, the OP had requested to loop over a list of conditions using `lapply()` "to do something". This can be achieved as follows

```
# create list of conditions for subsetting
col = list(c("a","b","c"), c("b","c"))
val = list(c(1, 1, 1), c(0, 1))
# loop over conditions
lapply(seq_along(col), function(i) test[as.list(val[[i]]), on = col[[i]], test2 := i])
#[[1]]
#
#[[2]]
#   a b c test2
#1: 1 0 1     2
#2: 1 1 1     1
#3: 0 0 1     2
```

Note that the output of `lapply()` is not used because `test` has been modified *in place*:

```
test
#   a b c test2
#1: 1 0 1     2
#2: 1 1 1     1
#3: 0 0 1     2
```