# Is dplyr easier than data.table to be used within functions and loops?

Tags: r, function, loops, iteration, dplyr

I'm comparing the convenience of `dplyr` vs. `data.table` in working within loops and functions.

For this, I'm trying to modify the code snippets used in this post: [data.table vs dplyr: can one do something well the other can't or does poorly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435339/data-table-vs-dplyr-can-one-do-something-well-the-other-cant-or-does-poorly) so that, instead of  hard-coded dataset variables names ("cut" and "price" variables of "diamonds" dataset), they become dataset-agnostic, i.e. cut-n-paste ready for the use inside any function or a loop (when we don't know column names in advance and need to access them by column number).

This is the original code:

```
tbl = diamonds
tbl %>%
  filter(cut != "Fair") %>%
  group_by(cut) %>%
  summarize(
     AvgPrice = mean(price)
  )
```

I need to rewrite it so that I can use the same code in a loop like this one:

```
for(nVarGroup in 2:4) # Grouped by possible categorical values...
   for(nVarMeans in 5:10) { # ... get means of all parameters

}
```

I've done it for `data.table` as shown here: [How to use data.table within functions and loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376032/how-to-use-data-table-within-functions-and-loops).
I'm struggling however to do the same for `dplyr`.
These links were recommended to resolve the problem: [dplyr: How to use group_by inside a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815060/dplyr-how-to-use-group-by-inside-a-function),  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html. 
However, while providing solution to  `group_by(strVarGroup)` line below, they do not not seem to provide solution to `qGroup=quote(get(strVarGroup) %in% strGroupConditions)` line.

```
nVarGroup = 2 #"cut"
nVarMeans = 7 #"price"

strVarGroup = names(dt)[nVarGroup]
strVarMeans = names(dt)[nVarMeans] 
qAction=quote(mean(strVarMeans)) 
strGroupConditions = levels(dt[[nVarGroup]])[-1] # "Good" "Very Good" "Premium" "Ideal" 
qGroup=quote(get(strVarGroup) %in% strGroupConditions) 

### DOES NOT WORK ###
tbl %>%
   filter(eval(qGroup))    %>%
   group_by(strVarGroup) %>%
   summarize(
     AvgPrice = eval(qAction),
     ) 
### END: DOES NOT WORK ###
```

Any additional links or ideas to help?

Comment: See `vignette(nse)`.