# Accessing by variable column name in data.table - Error: `cannot change value of locked binding for '.SD'`

Tags: r, loops, data.table

This is related to my earlier question on convenience of `data.table` for loops and functions: [How to use data.table within functions and loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376032/how-to-use-data-table-within-functions-and-loops) and related post: [Data.table meta-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790743/data-table-meta-programming).
This little code shows how conveniently this is done with `data.table` it is (e.g. compare to `dplyr`).

At first, I got `cannot change value of locked binding for '.SD'` error when I use `get(strY)` or `.SD` / `.SDcols=colY` below. But when I restarted the R Session, it all worked.

```
dt <- data.table(ggplot2::diamonds)
nY <- 1;                       nX <- c(5:7)
strY <- names(dt)[nY];         strX <- names(dt)[nX];        

dt[,strY, with=F] # OK
dt[,nY, with=F] # OK

dt[,get(strY)] # OK NOW: 
#NO MORE: Error in assign(ii, SDenv$.SDall[[ii]], SDenv) : 
#   cannot change value of locked binding for '.SD'
dt[, .SD, .SDcols=strX] # OK NOW: 
#NO MORE Error in assign(ii, SDenv$.SDall[[ii]], SDenv) : 
#   cannot change value of locked binding for '.SD'
```

Comment: I don't see the error you are "get"-ting. My console fills up with  53K values. Uggh.

Comment: Add `library()` statements. There is no diamonds data set available in my r session.

Comment: Anyway, `dt[, ..strY]` works fine for me, as does all of the code that is giving you errors.

Comment: You can find the link to delete your question below it. Otherwise, I guess you could post an answer further down, but I don't think this'll be of much benefit to future visitors.

Comment: I think this question is useful. Knowing that this error is solved by restarting the session clearly helped me. Maybe rephrase in a simpler way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem was resolved somehow by restarting the R session. - All lines work. This code has become the key work-stone for all my loop/function needs. Thanks to reviewers!