# Using by in data.table programmatically with an operation on a column

Tags: r, data.table

I want to use a character vector containing column names in `by` in `data.table` along with the interactive way of defining groups. The vector contains columns which are common across a few `data.table`s, but each `data.table` has a few unique columns. Is that possible? Example below.

```
library(data.table)
mtcarsdt <- data.table(mtcars)
bycols <- c('cyl', 'gear')   # Defined for use across multiple data.tables
mtcarsdt[
  , .(mpg = mean(mpg)),      # This does not work.
  by = c('carb%%2', bycols)  # How can I make this work?
]
mtcarsdt[
  , .(mpg = mean(mpg)), 
  by = .(carb%%2, cyl, gear) # This works
]
```

Comment: `%%2` is an arbitrary example of an operation on a column, which is possible in `by` as long as you pass the quoted arguments in a list. For this example, `%%2` could be replaced by `>2` just as easily.

Comment: @42- Why are the results incorrect? `mtcarsdt[cyl == 6 & gear == 4 & carb%%2 == 0, mean(mpg)]` yielded the same result (`19.75`) as the first row of the second query for me

Comment: I didn't understand what you were doing. I've now figured it out.

Comment: an ugly approach: `mtcarsdt[,
    .(mpg = mean(mpg)),
    by=eval(parse(text=paste0("list(carb%%2,", paste(bycols, collapse=","), ")")))
]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one work fully generically in data.table in R with column names in variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833247/how-can-one-work-fully-generically-in-data-table-in-r-with-column-names-in-varia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one very literal way of doing it:

```
mtcarsdt[, .(mpg = mean(mpg)), by = eval(as.call(parse(text = c(".", bycols, "carb %% 2"))))]
#    cyl gear carb      mpg
# 1:   6    4    0 19.75000
# 2:   4    4    1 29.10000
# 3:   6    3    1 19.75000
# 4:   8    3    0 14.63333
# 5:   4    4    0 24.75000
# 6:   8    3    1 16.30000
# 7:   4    3    1 21.50000
# 8:   4    5    0 28.20000
# 9:   8    5    0 15.40000
#10:   6    5    0 19.70000
```

Another option is constructing the whole expression and eval/parsing it:

```
bycols = "cyl, gear"
eval(parse(text = paste0('mtcarsdt[, .(mpg = mean(mpg)), by = .(carb %% 2, ', bycols, ')]')))
```

You can also play the same tricks using `eval`/`quote`.

And if you don't care about keeping `bycols` columns as columns, and mostly care about the grouping, you can also do:

```
mtcarsdt[, byvals := paste(.BY, collapse = ","), by = bycols][
         , .(mpg = mean(mpg)), by = .(byvals, carb %% 2)]
#    byvals carb      mpg
# 1:    6,4    0 19.75000
# 2:    4,4    1 29.10000
# 3:    6,3    1 19.75000
# 4:    8,3    0 14.63333
# 5:    4,4    0 24.75000
# 6:    8,3    1 16.30000
# 7:    4,3    1 21.50000
# 8:    4,5    0 28.20000
# 9:    8,5    0 15.40000
#10:    6,5    0 19.70000
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a 3 way interaction vector as the by argument:

```
mtcarsdt[
    , .(mpg = mean(mpg)),      # This does not work.
    by =  interaction(mtcars$carb%%2, interaction( mtcars[, bycols]))  # How can I make this work?
    ]

    interaction      mpg
 1:       0.6.4 19.75000
 2:       1.4.4 29.10000
 3:       1.6.3 19.75000
 4:       0.8.3 14.63333
 5:       0.4.4 24.75000
 6:       1.8.3 16.30000
 7:       1.4.3 21.50000
 8:       0.4.5 28.20000
 9:       0.8.5 15.40000
10:       0.6.5 19.70000
```

Comment: Thank you. Did not know about `interaction`. But is there any easy way to retrieve the original labels of the variables? (Or is that a separate question?)

Comment: (Dunno. Maybe?) The trick was to find a mechanism for each of the columns to be referred to using the same datatype. Your problem was to combine access using expressions using R symbols for columns with access via character vector reference to column names. There are so many different ways of formulating a `by` reference in data.table but I think there wasn't an effort to allow mixing of these reference-types.

Comment: Thanks! I'll wait for for a day and accept your answer if there are no better answers.

Answer (score 0):

this seems like an issue of splicing and evaluating `bycols` in a given environment. 
I am not too familiar with the data.table package. But since there are other answers I figured I can give an alternative process that does what you require.
The trick is to use the `rlang` `!!!` operator with `syms`.
What this does is splices the `bycols` vector and evaluates it. Easily done with `dplyr` grouping and summarising.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
bycols <- c("cyl", "gear")
mtcarsdt %>% mutate(carb2 = carb%%2) %>% 
  group_by(carb2, !!! syms(bycols)) %>% 
  summarise(m_mpg = mean(mpg))
```

Now `bycols` can be whatever columns you like.