# compare rows by reference in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

In the search, I found a lot of questions on how to do this for columns, but not for rows.

```
# Works just fine:
data = as.data.table(iris)
head(data[Species == 'setosa'])

# I want to do it programatically:
varname = 'Species'
head(data[varname == 'setosa']) # Doesn't work
head(data[(varname) == 'setosa']) # Doesn't work
head(data[(varname) == 'setosa', with = F]) # Doesn't work
```

Any advice on the correct syntax here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: also you might find this answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833247/how-can-one-work-fully-generically-in-data-table-in-r-with-column-names-in-varia/54800108#54800108

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `get`

```
head(data[get(varname) == 'setosa'])
```

or `eval(as.name`

```
head(data[eval(as.name(varname)) == 'setosa'])
```

Comment: Ugh, I should have known. Thanks!