# Passing multiple column names to "by" in a data.table function

Tags: r, function, data.table

I've read many posts on passing column names to a data.table function, but I did not see a post dealing with passing multiple variables to "by". I commonly use code like this to calculate summary statistics by group.

```
# Data
library(data.table)
dt=mtcars
setDT(dt)

# Summary Stats Example
dt[cyl==4,.(Count=.N,
    Mean=mean(hp),
    Median=median(hp)),
    by=.(am,vs)]

#    am vs Count   Mean Median
# 1:  1  1     7 80.571     66
# 2:  0  1     3 84.667     95
# 3:  1  0     1 91.000     91
```

I can't get the following function to work:

```
# Function
myFun <- function(df,i,j,by){
    df[i==4,.(Count=.N,
      Mean=mean(j),
      Median=median(j)),
      by=.(am,by)]
}
myFun(dt,i='cyl',j='hp',by='vs')
```

Note that I hard-coded "4" and "am" into the function for this example. `get()` worked when only using 1 by grouping variable, but failed when multiple grouping variables are used. Guidance on how to properly use get/quote/eval/substitute/parse/as.name/etc when writing data.table functions is appreciated.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1191259%20%5bdata.table%5d%20substitute or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833247/how-can-one-work-fully-generically-in-data-table-in-r-with-column-names-in-varia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a character vector for `by` part of `data.table`, it will work:

```
myFun <- function(df, i, j, by){

 df[get(i) == 4, .(Count = .N, 
           Mean = mean(get(j)),
           Median = median(get(j))),
  by = c(by, 'am')]
}



myFun(dt, i = 'cyl', j = 'hp', by = 'vs')

#vs am Count     Mean Median
#1:  1  1     7 80.57143     66
#2:  1  0     3 84.66667     95
#3:  0  1     1 91.00000     91
```

Comment: `eval(by)` is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks @sm925 and @sindri_baldur. I noticed that the above code changed the by argument from a list to a vector. My example does not show it, but I typically apply criteria (eg `grp>2`) in the by argument, so for my general purposes I need to use `by=.()`.

Comment: Your responses helped me craft the following cheat sheet:   
- Pass i, j, and by variables using `get(var)`  
- Pass i or by criteria directly  
  
The above assumes `by` is a list. The above may fail or be considered bad practice in more complicated scenarios. For example, I use `merge()` instead of taking advantage of `[` to join two data.tables.

Answer (score 0):

I've accepted sm95's answer. Below is a more complex example/solution that sends a list to the `by` argument:

```
# Libraries
library(data.table)

# Data
dt = mtcars
setDT(dt)

# Function to calculate summary statistics
myFun <- function(df, i1var, i1val, i2var, i2val,            # i arguments
                                    j,                       # j arguments
                                    by1var, by2var, by2val){ # by arguments
    df[get(i1var) == i1val & get(i2var) %in% i2val,
         .(Count = .N,
            Mean = mean(get(j)),
            Median = median(get(j))),
        by = .(get(by1var), get(by2var) == by2val)]
} # END Function

# Run function
myFun(dt,i1var = 'cyl', i1val = 4, i2var = 'gear', i2val = c(3,4),
            j = 'hp',
            by1var = 'vs', by2var = 'am', by2val = 1)
#    vs am Count     Mean Median
# 1:  1  1     6 75.16667     66
# 2:  1  0     3 84.66667     95

# Should match
dt[cyl == 4 & gear %in% c(3,4),
     .(Count = .N,
        Mean = mean(hp),
        Median = median(hp)),
     by = .(vs, am == 1)]
#    vs am Count     Mean Median
# 1:  1  1     6 75.16667     66
# 2:  1  0     3 84.66667     95
```

Here is my Cheat Sheet:

- Pass `i`, `j`, and `by` variables using `get(var)`
- Pass `i` or `by` criteria directly

The above may not apply to more complex functions, and may not be optimal.

If `by` is a vector and NOT a list (eg, `by=c()` vs `by=.()`), then `by` arguments can be passed directly.