# Programmatically change the values in the column of a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with columns A, B and C

A | B | C

1 | 1 | 2

2 | 1 | 2

2 | 3 | 1

I want to change the values of each column to "True" (if the row value == 2) or "False" otherwise, programmatically.

I know that `dt[, A := fifelse(A == 2, "True", "False"]` works, but how do I pass in the columns as a variable? Something like `dt[, cols := fifelse(cols := 2, "True", "False"]`, where cols = "A"

Comment: Related Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833247/how-can-one-work-fully-generically-in-data-table-in-r-with-column-names-in-varia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to leave it as boolean `TRUE/FALSE` instead of a string "True", "False"

```
dt[, A := A == 2]
```

If we need to pass a variable and it is only for a single column, `get` can be used

```
dt[, (cols) := get(cols) == 2]
```

If there are more than one column, specify it in `.SDcols`, loop over the `.SD`, convert to logical and assign (`:=`) it back to the strings of object

```
dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, `==`, 2), .SDcols = cols]
```